# Trouble understanding resuming cells in collection views

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm following a site to help learn swift and I'm getting confused about this part right here. Basically  we added the if cell.imageview.image == nil statement so hat when the collection view loads and you scroll the image doesn't reload the filters. What I don't understand is if you scroll down a cell is reused for the bottom row, now why if I scroll back up doesn't it have to reload the filter? is that data saved somewhere so when I scroll up the  properties don't have to repopulate? and If thats the case why would I have to use that if statement at all?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FilterCell

    if cell.imageView.image == nil {
        cell.imageView.image = placeholder

        let filterQueue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("filter queue", nil)

        dispatch_async(filterQueue, { () -> Void in
            let filterImage = self.filteredImageFromImage(self.thisFeeditem.thumbNail, filter: self.filters[indexPath.row])

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                cell.imageView.image = filterImage
            })
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a cell is reused, a cell object that was already allocated is just used again. Any properties or data that was set to it will remain.

When you scroll back up, the cell has already had it's image set, and so it won't reload the new filtered image.

Comment: Ok, thats the answer I was looking for. Now how come in the collection view the data changes. For example the blur filter that would appear at the top, when I scroll down is now at the bottom?

Comment: I would need more information about how you're implementing your filter to take a shot at that one!

Comment: Where do the properties remain though cause if its reused, art the properties overridden by the data

Comment: The properties are only overridden if you override them again in your 'cellForItemAtIndexPath' method. The cell that is returned from `dequeueReusableCell...` is just the old object being returned again after calling `prepareForReuse` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Cells can be reused whether you scroll up or down. You should assume the cell returned is a cached version for a different item. Therefore it may already be bound with another cell's data and you'd want to always rebind the cell with the proper items' data.